# TinyMCE + Safari 3 - Table insertion does not work

Tags: javascript, safari, tinymce

Has anyone else had this issue and found a working solution? I've enabled the Safari compatibility plugin, but it still behaves incorrectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php

Shrug, works fine for me.